# Get current url and create share link (yahoo messenger)

Tags: hyperlink, share, yahoo

I have this function to get the current page url:

```
<?php
function currentPageURL() {
$curpageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$curpageURL.= "s";}
$curpageURL.= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$curpageURL.= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$curpageURL.= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
return $curpageURL;
}
echo currentPageURL();
?>
```

And I need to create a link to share the page's URL by a **href**.

I tried:

```
<a href="ymsgr:im?+&msg=<?=$currentPageURL;?>" title="Send on yahoo">Link</a>
```

But I'm not getting the `currentPageURL`; it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on this one. Seems like you're using a variable and not the function call in your href. This should work:

`<a href="ymsgr:im?+&msg=<?=currentPageURL();?>" title="Send on yahoo">Link</a>`